# convert a timetuple to a timestamp then convert the timestamp back ,the new timetuple is not the original timetuple

Tags: python, time

Using `time.mktime()` convert a timetuple to a timestamp then using `time.gmtime()` convert the timestamp back to a new timetuple. The new timetuple is not the original timetuple.

[image: just like this ,using python 2.7 and jupyter]

```
tmp = datetime.datetime.strptime('130701 00:00:00', '%y%m%d %H:%M:%S').timetuple()

tmp
# time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=7, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=182, tm_isdst=-1)
time.gmtime(time.mktime(tmp))
# time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=30, tm_hour=16, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=181, tm_isdst=0)
```

Comment: Please include your code as text rather than as an image, so anyone wanting to help you can copy it straight into their editor.

Comment: I can't reproduce this - [see here](https://repl.it/repls/GleefulPettyAuk).

Comment: Do you happen to be living in GMT+8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue. Use `time.localtime`, not `time.gmtime`:

```
time.localtime(time.mktime(tmp))
```